# parole player gives Gstreamer error when CD/DVD played in XUBUNTU

Tags: xubuntu, video, encryption, dvd

No matter which DVD or CD I try to play using parole player in Xubuntu. I get the following error for CD's 
:Could not handle CDDA URI:GStreamer backend error :
And the following for DVD's:
 Could not read DVD. This may be because the DVD is encrypted and a DVD decryption library is not installed.

Question: Should I just purge this player and install another type? Or is there a fix for this?
What about using something like "blender?" would that player, play both music and video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parole & audio cd playback is bugged, see here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/parole/+bug/1322384

Comment 4 may work for you, you can test by putting an audio cd in & then from a terminal

`parole --device=% cdda://`

For dvd's make sure libdvdcss2 is installed -

```
sudo apt-get install  libdvdnav4 && \
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

As far as other players many better than parole are available, search around.

audacious is good for audio, vlc is good for dvd's, ect.